# In my unit tescases I want to load h2 scripts only one time

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, junit

I am using spring boot with JPA in my project, I have created unit test and using h2 database but in unit test before every class h2 database is loading and running DDL and DML script but I want to restrict to only one-time load and run DDL and DML

Comment: Your question is broad. Please give a specific example of your test. And for which reason do you want to execute the database init a single time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your unit test ***should not*** depend on any external script.

- It makes your tests depend on some external factor, which makes your tests failing even when that external factor fails for some other reason.
- One can never get an idea on your test cases by only seeing your test case code.

The correct way to address your matter is writing a `@DataJPATest` with using  `TestEntityManager`, you can refer an example from [here](https://hellokoding.com/spring-boot-test-data-layer-example-with-datajpatest/).